# Why doesn’t pain return after a tooth extraction once the local anesthesia wears off?

Tags: dentistry, pain, anesthesia, tooth-extraction

Tooth extraction involves removing a tooth from its socket, which can create a hole in the gum and jawbone and potentially cause pain. Local anesthesia is used during the procedure to numb the area and prevent pain. After the procedure, the anesthesia gradually wears off and sensation returns to the area. However, many people do not experience significant pain after the extraction. I am curious about the reasons behind this lack of pain.

Why doesn’t pain return after a tooth extraction once the local anesthesia wears off?

Comment: Because the tooth was the source of the pain?

Comment: @CareyGregoryisonstrike Even after the anesthesia wears off, the **hole** created by tooth extraction in the jaw is still present, increasing the chance for pain to return. Then why the pain isn’t returning, despite the presence of the **hole**?

Comment: That hole has been there since the day your first baby tooth erupted and extracting a tooth doesn't make it larger or damage tissue. So why do you expect it to hurt?

Comment: @CareyGregoryisonstrike is correct; the "hole" left by the tooth has always been there, and the tooth's main nerves (contained in the pulp) are extracted with the tooth.  However, with teeth (primarily wisdom teeth) which have very deep roots and take a lot of wiggling back and forth, side to side to loosen and extract them, post-extraction pain meds are required because the jaw's periosteum has been injured.